# How to stop closing wizard when try to open another wizard by button in Odoo 10

Tags: button, odoo, odoo-10, wizard

I have a wizard and i added button on that wizard. And When i tried to open another wizard on that wizard by button then it close the previous wizard and opened new wizard. So, How to stop closing previous wizard when open new wizard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I spent lots of hours fighting with this issue. I modified JS code of odoo backend. Unfortunately odoo had stuggles with two opened wizards. While losing second wizard, first was beeing closed. etc

Comment: Yes, That's Problem.

Comment: This is a built in function of odoo framework. For what purpose you want to do like this?